# uninitialized constant Compass in rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

I was trying to use [fancy-buttons](https://github.com/imathis/fancy-buttons) gem in my rails 3 app but now I can not even start my local server because of this error:

> $:~/rails/project$ rails server
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fancy-buttons-1.0.6/lib/fancy-buttons.rb:1: uninitialized constant Compass
>   (NameError)

This is what my gemfile looks like:

```
gem "fancy-buttons"
gem 'haml' 
gem 'haml-rails' 
gem 'compass', ">= 0.10.6"
```

I've ran `bundle update` and `bundle install`

```
Using haml (3.0.25) 
Using compass (0.10.6) 
Using fancy-buttons (1.0.6)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compass needs to come before fancy-buttons in your gemfile.  This ensures that it is loaded before fancy-buttons tries to require it as the gems in your gemfile are loaded in order.